# Why does passing an unnamed function as transform to array add one to iteration count in playground in furthest abstractions

Tags: swift

I'm in the process of getting comfortable passing unnamed functions as arguments and I am using this to practice with, based off of the examples in [the Swift Programming Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1)

So we have an array of `Int`s:

```
var numbers: Int[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And I apply a transform like so: (7)

```
func transformNumber(number: Int) -> Int {
    let result = number * 3
    return result
}

numbers = numbers.map(transformNumber)
```

Which is equal to: (7)

```
numbers = numbers.map({(number: Int) -> Int in
    let result = number * 3
    return result;
    })
```

Which is equal to: (8)

```
numbers = numbers.map({number in number * 3})
```

Which is equal to: (8)

```
numbers = numbers.map({$0 * 3})
```

Which is equal to: (8)

```
numbers = numbers.map() {$0 * 3}
```

As you can see in the following graphic, the iteration count in the playground sidebar shows that in the furthest abstraction of a function declaration, it has an 8 count.

[image]

#### Question

Why is it showing as 8 iterations for the last two examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not showing 8 iterations, really. It's showing that 8 things executed on that line. There were 7 executions as part of the `map` function, and an 8th to do the assignment back into the `numbers` variable.

It looks like this could probably provide more helpful diagnostics. I would highly encourage you to provide feedback via https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: While it may appear that the extra count is for the assignment back to `numbers`, that isn't so. Removing the assignment still results in eight calls. See my answer below for other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly rewriting your experiment to use only closures, the call counts still differ by one:

Case 1: Explicitly specifying argument types (visit count is 7)

```
var f1 = {(number: Int) -> Int  in
  let result = number * 3
  return result
}
numbers.map(f1)
```

Case 2: Implicit argument types (visit count is 8)

```
var f2 = {$0 * 3}
numbers.map(f2)
```

If the (`x` times) count reported by the REPL does indeed represent a count of visits to that code location, and noting that the count is greater by one in cases where the closure type arguments are not explicitly specified (e.g. `f2`), my guess is that at least in the playground REPL, the extra visit is to establish actual parameter types and fill that gap in the underlying AST.